# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem (Edx Course example)

Tags: java, eclipse, class, intellij-idea, println

I'm learning JAVA with the Edx course presented by Microsoft and I'm repeating the examples on their videos but there's this error that keeps showing whenever I compile:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at var.main(var.java:3)
```

Here's my code which is basically the same as the one in the video tutorial:

```
public class var {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int x= 12;
        System.out.println("my number is" + x);
    }

}
```

I use Eclipse IDE while theirs is IntelliJ 
I hope you can point out the mistake. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the same JDK as they are using? I suspect you are using JDK 11 (or higher) and the course is using JDK 8 (or the likes). Try renaming your class from `var` to something else like `Main`. (also notice the uppercase letter as that is general convention).

Comment: Note: by convention class names start with Uppercase letter (not imposed but it is what most developers expect and are used to - so probably this is also the case in mentioned video)

Comment: I'm used to work with python and this is only my second code in Java so I didn't know that naming it var would cause an issue. Thanks for pointing that out, it's really helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the name of your class. Since Java version 10 `var` is not allowed as a type name (JLS §3.8 [TypeIdentifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-3.html#jls-TypeIdentifier) `Var` would be OK.

Comment: It worked when I changed the name of the class. Thank you.